# Why the value of my function does not update with the value of my object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm doing an exercise about rover in Mars I have the object rover that has direction as property and default value 'N' (north), he needs first turn before to go forward, it means that if the rover wants to move to the left, it’s first move must be a turn, next move will then be a step forward. when I run the function to moveLeft(rover) The results are as expected. He turns perfect!! BUT the value of property direction is never updated, and I need this value update to the next step... I'm going to paste a part of my code. Thank you!

```
  direction: 'E',
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  path: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  travelLog: []
}
var move = rover.direction

function moveLeft (who) {
  console.log(`Rover is facing ${move}`)
  switch (move) {
    case 'N':
      move = 'W'
      console.log(`Rover is facing now ${move}`)
      break;
    case 'W':
      move = 'S'
      console.log(`Rover is facing now ${move}`)
      break;
    case 'S':
      move = 'E'
      console.log(`Rover is facing now ${move}`)
      break;
    case 'E':
      move = 'N'
      console.log(`Rover is facing now ${move}`)
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`Please insert the correct directions`)
  }
  console.log('turnLeft was called!')
}
```

This is my output

```
Rover is facing E
Rover is facing now N
turnLeft was called!

console.log(rover)
{direction: "E", x: 0, y: 0, path: {…}, travelLog: Array(0)}

console.log(move)
W

console.log(rover.direction)
E

I expect the output of rover.direction to be the same of move
```

Comment: I would agree with the answer and I want to add that it'd be good if you look into 2 topics, namely passing by value and by reference (which works in the same way). The question here may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
var move = rover.direction
```

is copying the *value* of `rover.direction` into the variable named `move`, it does not create a reference to `rover.direction`. When you do something like this:

```
move = 'W'
```

it only updates the `move` variable, it does *not* update `rover.direction`.

To fix this, you can either add a line like:

```
rover.direction = move;
```

after your `switch` statement, or you can get rid of the `move` variable and work directly on `rover.direction`.

Also, a couple notes/suggestions:

1. You are defining `move` outside of the `moveLeft` function. That creates another global variable in addition to the global `rover` variable. In general, you want to limit the number of global variables to be as few as possible.
2. Your `moveLeft` function takes a `who` parameter that you are not currently using within the function. From your description, it looks like you intend to pass the `rover` variable in that parameter. In that case, you probably want to remove all references to `move` and just work with `who.direction` within your function.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(the other answer already covered why your current work doesn't work as expected)</sub>

I'd write it as:

```js
const turns = ["N", "W", "S", "E"]; // We can easily look up the direction to the right or left here

function turnLeft(rover) {
  console.log(`Rover is facing ${rover.direction}`);
  
  const pos = turns.indexOf(rover.direction); // get the current position, e.g. E => 3
  rover.direction = turns[(pos + 1) % turns.length]; // Increase the position by 1 (=> 0), make sure it's inside the turns arrays indices by starting again from 0 (=> 0), then look that up => "N"
  
  console.log(`Rover is facing now ${rover.direction}`)
}


const rover = { direction: "E" };
turnLeft(rover);
turnLeft(rover);
```